# moto g cyanogenmod 11 android 4.4.4

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting, 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

Are there any links for cyanogenmod 11 for moto g android 4.4.4?
If there are then please suggest me the one which is stable,equipped with the theme engine and is under 100mb.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all official CyanogenMod downloads for Moto G (`falcon`) [here.](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=falcon&type=)

Although you must understand that Android custom ROMs virtually were never under 100MB in size; if they were, it was before Android 2.x. KitKat ROMs nowadays usually fall within 200MB.